# Angular http subscribe blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors, same-origin-policy

I am sending form data to a api which is running in python flask. The form is in angular 11. When using httpclient the api is not accessible.

```
this.http.post('http://192.168.0.95:5001/login', formData).subscribe(

  (response) => console.log(response),
  (error) => console.log(error)
)
```

But when i directly submit the form to that api its working.

```
<form action ="http://192.168.0.95:5001/login">
```

I have updated the proxy.conf.json file as below

```
{
    "/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

but its not working. Anyone please help with this

Comment: That proxy config doesn't make sense; it doesn't have the right target, and given that you're making the requests directly to the target the proxy won't get hit anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score -1):

By default browser will block cross platform request.
You need to configure access on server.

For more details please check this:
https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have done like this. But its not working